# How to check status of toggle button in selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium

Hi Guys I want to put assertion on the value of toggle button(on/off) but I'm not able to fetch the value for the same.
The code I'm using to get value is:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"map1\"]/map-settings/div[3]/ul/li[2]/label/input").click()
 val = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"map1\"]/map-settings/div[3]/ul/li[2]/label/input").get_attribute("value")
 return val
```

But I'm unable to do so.
The HTML code for the element is:

```
      <li _ngcontent-xuq-65="" class="text-element">
                        Select All
    <label _ngcontent-xuq-65="" class="toggle col-sm-8">
      <input _ngcontent-xuq-65="" type="checkbox">
      <span _ngcontent-xuq-65="" class="handle"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
```

Please refer to Images attached to see the snippet of toggle and the IDE recording of elements for further enlightenment.[image]

Comment: Can you share the HTML of a record that has a value? I have an idea of what is going on but want to be sure.

Comment: I have already shared the HTML code needed..Please tell if you want something else

Comment: Which element is the Value element? Your question is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a value attribute when there is no value attribute in your  HTML. Use the text property instead. This will work if there actually is a value in the field you are attempting to pull.

```
val = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"map1\"]/map-settings/div[3]/ul/li[2]/label/input").text;
```